# Excel - from a business card layout to a simple table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import data from an excel - sheet that has this layout:

[image]

I would like to convert this into a simple table like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple macro to loop through your data

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vDst As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    vSrc = Worksheets("SourceData").UsedRange
    ReDim vDst(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1) * UBound(vSrc, 2) / 3, 1 To 3)
    i = 1
    For c = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        For r = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1) - 2 Step 3
            vDst(i, 1) = vSrc(r, c)
            vDst(i, 2) = vSrc(r + 1, c)
            vDst(i, 3) = vSrc(r + 2, c)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next
    Worksheets("DestData").Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(vDst), 3) = vDst
End Sub
```